# Handling Streams Without Conflict

Tags: node.js

I'm iterating over an array of uri's that are obtained and I would like to know how I can properly control these streams while successfully writing the image files and only receive the amount of images specified in `max`? Somehow, this is still ignoring the count.

**Outline**

1. Write the image
2. Output the count of the downloaded image
3. Exit if count of max is reached.

**edit:**

```
var count = 1;
var max = 1000;

images.each(function (index, element) {
  var uri = element.attribs.src;
  request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(output(uri)))
    .on('data', function () {
      console.log('[' + chalk.green('+') + ']' + ' wrote image ' + count);
      sleep.sleep(1); // pause between requests
    });
    .on('end', function () {
      count++;
      if (count === max) {
        process.exit(0);
      }
    });
    .on('error', function () {
      console.log('[' + chalk.red('x') + ']' + ' failed to write image');                                                                                                                    
    });
  });
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to process all of the items in `images` but want a max concurrency (max items being processed at any given time) of 1000?

Comment: Here's what I'm trying to do: I'm downloading images, but I would only like as many as max. At the same time, I want to make sure the images have been properly downloaded. @mscdex Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I've made an edit, that should outline more on what I want. @mscdex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possible solution:

```
var left = 1000,
    imagesChunk = images.slice(0, left);

function onDone() {
  // we're done!
}

left = imagesChunk.length;
imagesChunk.each(function (index, element) {
  var uri = element.attribs.src;
  var stream = request(uri);
  var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(output(uri));
  var hadError = false;
  stream.on('error', function(err) {
          if (hadError)
            return;
          console.log('[' + chalk.red('✗') + ']');
          writeStream.close();
          hadError = true;
        })
        .pipe(writeStream)
          .on('error', function(err) {
            if (hadError)
              return;
            console.log('[' + chalk.red('✗') + ']');
            stream.destroy();
            hadError = true;
          })
          .on('close', function() {
            if (!hadError)
              console.log('[' + chalk.green('✓') + ']');
            if (--left === 0)
              onDone();
          });
});
```

Comment: I'm assuming onDone is where I could pause between each image request. Something like ```(Math.random() * (3 - 1) + 1) | 0;``` right? @mscdex

Comment: It wouldn't be a "pause" because the `.each()` is iterating over the entire array at once. The `onDone()` is what is called all images have been processed. Are you saying you only want one outstanding request at any given time?

Comment: I would like to print that when each image is written, console.log the image count and then pause between each request. That way I'm not blowing up their server and it appears natural. For example: ```[+] wrote image 1... wrote image 2...``` until it reached max. @mscdex